# How to remove *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* from email title using Mailchimp and or Mandrill

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

I have created an email template which includes merging tags on MailChimp which then gets published to Mandrill.

When my script runs and I receive email, as you can see, *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* appears in the title.

[image]

I have searched both Mandrill and MailChimp for this tag but it is not appearing in either template file.

How do I remove this from the email?

Comment: Worst thing about this issue is when customers email us and try to explain how to fix it. And you don't even know how to reply...

Answer (score 14):

I used to do this through Mandrill template editor.
[image]

Simply remove these lines which appears just after the body opening:

```
    <!--*|IF:MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|*-->
            <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!----><span class="mcnPreviewText"  
 style="display:none; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; opacity:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">*|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|*</span>
           <!--<![endif]-->
           <!--*|END:IF|*-->
```

To know more about this merge tag:
https://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet

> Use this merge tag to generate preview text in a custom-coded
> campaign. Insert *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* just after the opening < body >
> tag in your HTML. To ensure the preview text isn’t visible in the body
> of your campaign, wrap the merge tag in a hidden < span > element.
>
> Locate or add  < style type= "text / css" > < /script >  to your HTML,
> and add this code to the "style type" value:
>
> After the opening < body > tag, add:
> [image]

**Hint**: Search in the browser for this text doesn't work for some reason, search for something written in the code didn't work for me on chrome with Mandrill, so unfortunate find it by eye or copy-paste to an external editor.

Comment: *MC_PREVIEW_TEXT* is still shown in the email although my code in mandrill is not including the code block that you mentioned in the answer. In addition to that I am sending the merge tags from java code and specifying the language of the template as handlebars although the non handlebar *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* tag is still appearing. any suggestions?

Comment: @JadChahine are you sure you save and published the template from Mandrill after removing these lies? also not that these lines are copied back to the template when you push the template from Mailchimp again. give me a screen shot of your template code, may be a i can figure out the issue and compare it with mine.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0s1upZA7YV1WlFLM3Q3bTJBTmc/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0s1upZA7YV1bmdrcmktMUlwY2s/view?usp=sharing

thank you

Comment: in fact, those lines were not available in the template like your case. i don't have those lines i just have the lines that i posted in the previous comment and i am setting the language as handlebar from the code. but the MC_PREVIEW_DATA tag still appears in the email.

Comment: @JadChahine Yes, I see, where is your body tag?

Comment: i have no body tag, but now i add it to the template, save and publish to mandrill then try to send an email, still have the MC_PREVIEW_TEXT appeared.

Comment: @JadChahine that's quite odd, what I am sure from that any text appears on your email for sure it is coming from the template source code, there is no magic places, so make sure you are calling the correct Template and that there is no caching in your app. and let me know if still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154983/discussion-between-amr-elgarhy-and-jad-chahine).

Comment: Finally.. it is working now. I just found that the way that i am creating a template in mailchimp is a way where mailchimp generate an auto html code (other than my own html that i wrote in the editor) this auto generated code that i cannot handle contains the code block that you mentioned in your answer, I found this by looking into the inspect element of the mailchimp editor page. I found another way where i can write my own html code from scratch without any autogenerated html code. anyway thanks man for helping!

Comment: If you export the HTML in mailchimp, you can see the field. After you delete (as described above), import it directly in Mandrill.

Comment: Not sure why this is even in there.  Its a real pain having to remove it each time.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem and it was because I am using Handlebars as the Merge Language when sending emails.

Mailchimp is putting the MC_PREVIEW_TEXT variable in the template using the Mailchimp merge language, so if you use Handlebars, it shows up.

To fix this, you have to set your Merge Language to Handlebars in Mandrill Settings -> Sending Defaults.

But when you do this, you have to use Mailchimp merge language when designing your emails in Mailchimp, you can't use Handlebars.

Then when you send to Mandrill from Mailchimp, it will convert all your merge variables to Handlebars.

Comment: I hope MailChimp/Mandrill will look into this. It's not possible to change all our templates (thousands) to handlebars, so changing the default is not an option for us. But we try to do new templates using handlebars merge language, and now we have to manually modify html templates in Mandrill after updating the template form MailChip. Tedious and error prone.

Comment: I tried this and it fixed the preview issue but none of my handlebars are replaced by the values now.  They appear directly in the email. e.g. Hello {{firstName}}

Comment: @MadMac, you have to switch to the other template style fully.  `*|firstName|*`  I found that if I changed that setting and ensured that the API request also set the merge method to Mailchimp I could get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

There's two approaches we use:

1. **Via Mandrill REST API**: Using your API key in your POSTed request body, hit the [/templates/info.json](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html#method=info) endpoint, replace the offending markup, then forward the modified object to [/templates/update.json](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.JSON.html#method=update)
2. **Via GUI**: Mandrill [exposes a GUI](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582507-Getting-Started-with-Templates) to modify templates that lets you touch more code than Mailchimp's editor. Just delete it there.

Last I checked, the `MC_PREVIEW_TEXT` tag will reappear each time you send your Mailchimp templates to Mandrill. Pick what's best for you and stick to Mandrill for modifying Handlebars templates in the future.

Comment: Once logged in you can go to https://mandrillapp.com/templates, or choose 'Templates' under the 'Outbound' tab

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue, so I wrote simple rake task for our ROR app, which removes |MC_PREVIEW_TEXT| section from Mandrill templates automatically. Here an example of my rake task:

```
require 'mandrill'
namespace :mandrill do
  desc 'Removes *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* section for all email templates in mandrill app'
  task remove_mc_preview_text: :environment do

    # Templates with handlebars merge language
    templates = [
      'template-example-1',
      'template-example-2',
    ]

    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new 'YOUR_API_KEY'

    templates.each do |name|
      begin
        puts "Processing the template: #{name}"

        # Get the information for an existing template
        result = mandrill.templates.info name

        # Finds the section with MC_PREVIEW_TEXT inside a template and substitutes it to the empty string
        code = result['code'].sub(/\<\!\-\-\*\|IF:MC_PREVIEW_TEXT[[:ascii:]]+END:IF\|\*\-\-\>/m, '')

        # If nil is provided for any fields, the values will remain unchanged.
        from_email = nil
        from_name = nil
        subject = nil
        text = nil
        labels = nil

        # Set to false to update the draft version of the template without publishing
        publish = true

        # Update the code for an existing template
        mandrill.templates.update name, from_email, from_name, subject, code, text, publish, labels

        puts "Successfully deleted *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* section from the template: #{name}"
      rescue Mandrill::Error => e
        # Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
        puts "A mandrill error occurred: #{e.class} - #{e.message}"
      end
    end
    puts 'Done!'
  end
end
```

There are few steps should be done to make it work:

1. Install the Mandrill API client as a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mandrill-api): `gem install mandrill-api` or add to your Gemfile: `gem 'mandrill-api'`
2. Create any rake task (for example remove_mc_preview_text.rake) with the code listed above inside the lib/tasks/ folder
3. Change 'YOUR_API_KEY' to your real Mandrill API Key
4. Change template names in `templates` array to your real templates, if for some reason you don't know them, you can find them here https://mandrillapp.com/templates

And finally run this command in the root folder of your rails app:

```
bundle exec rake mandrill:remove_mc_preview_text
```

If you use any other programming language you can write similar script using my as an example, see [Mandrill API Clients](https://mandrillapp.com/docs/integrations.html) for different programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Remove following lines from your html code:

```
 <span class="m_-63420320203924518mcnPreviewText" style="display:none;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden">*|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|*</span>
```

After this insert your html code in the body of your mail.
Now your problem should be solved ....

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with Mailchimp template editor for sending templates to Mandrill. Also there was an issue with `https://` appended to handlebars tag by  Mailchimp template editor which forced us to remove `https://` from urls in payload. So to fix `MC_PREVIEW_TEXT`and issue with urls I created a Firefox extension.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mandrillchimp/

The only thing you need to do is create "special" Mandrill API Key which will allow extension to get and update template (info and update permissions).

Comment: looks nice. How secure is installing an addon and give access to the MailChimp account data?

Answer (score 1):

open html file and then `ctrl+f` , then use `|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|` to search and replace your text instead of it

Answer (score 0):

Preview text is pre-header text that will show when populated. From experience I have seen merge tags appear in tests. There is two things you can do:

1. Add text in the data file for the preview text Basically it will be the same for everyone or
2. You can add it to the template in MailChimp.

How to change pre header:
[image: changing pre header]

Cheers

Comment: How would I add it to the template on MailChimp? I do not want to use this Merge Tag. Sorry I am confused

Comment: All emails use preheader which acts as an extention to the subject line. Search for pre header & litmus which you give you more info. If you don't want to use it then you can place a space in place of it. I updated my post with screenshot of where you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help some of you wondering how to do it.

I had the issue when exporting a HTML template from MailChimp into Intercom.

Line numbers may be different, so copy HTML code into notepad/text edit and search *|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|* to find it

[Video with instructions](https://www.useloom.com/share/794cfc5cde694c8ca3510f91d6fee52e).

Answer (score 0):

I use Mailchimp templates exported to my Linux and Mac server (Teamcity agents). So I replace patterns with pretty text using sed:

```sql
# replace
sed -i 's/*|MC\:SUBJECT|*//' *.html
sed -i 's/*|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|\*//' *.html
```

For those who need a mail command at the same place:

```sql
# send email
html="/path/to/html"

# linux agent
mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s "Subject #%build.counter%" user@example.com <"$html"

# mac agent
/opt/homebrew/bin/mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s "Subject #%build.counter%" user@example.com <"$html"
```